# Opening PDF in browser at a specific page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, razor

I am using a custom html helper `@Html.ActionLink` to find and return a PDF file to the browser and open in a new tab. The issue I am now having is when I am trying to open the PDF on a specific page.

The file is found, returned and opened just fine when NOT trying to specify a page parameter for the PDF to open on. Therefore, there must be some issue with my approach to setting the parameter.

According to Adobe documentation, `#page=?` parameters can be appended to the end of a URL to open a PDF at a specific page. However, my approach for doing so is not working.

See Adobe documentation on the subject [here.](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf)

**Razor helper in use:**

```
@Html.FileLink("Document Link", "\\MyLocation\\MyDocument.pdf", "4", new { @target = "_blank" })
```

**Helper method:**

```
public static MvcHtmlString FileLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string LinkText, string FilePath, string PageNumber, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    return helper.ActionLink(LinkText, "ShowFile", "Home", new { path = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(FilePath), page = PageNumber }, htmlAttributes);
}
```

**ShowFile method:**

```
public ActionResult ShowFile(string path, string page)
{
    // My attempt at passing and setting the page parameter!
    path = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(path + "#page=" + page);

    // Get actual path to file, file name
    var filePath = string.Format("{0}{1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentsRoot"], path);

    // Get MIME type
    var contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);

    // Return file
    return File(filePath, contentType);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page parameter in the adobe documentation is an anchor tag (e.g. `#page=5`), not a query string parameter (`?page=5`).  You can use a different `ActionLink` override to specify this at the same time:

```
Html.ActionLink(LinkText, "ShowFile", "Home", null, null, "page=" + PageNumber, 
    new { path = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(FilePath) }, null)
```

This will generate a link which looks like...

> /Home/ShowFile?path=myfilename.txt#page=5

instead of

> /Home/ShowFile?path=myfilename.txt&page=5

You can then remove the page parameter from your ShowFile method, because it is only needed on the client side.

Comment: Thanks Richard, this is definitely what I need by the looks of it. However, the PDF is still failing to load... It seems it is now returning a `Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password` error when inspecting the response in Firebug. Very strange.

Comment: I suspect your webserver (IIS?) doesn't have permission to access the files on your network share.

Comment: The thing is, the file opens perfectly fine when I remove the page parameter stuff from the logic which makes this error even stranger

Comment: Did you remove the page number parameter from your ShowFile action method? You were previously trying to open \\mylocation\a.txt#page=5, which is not valid.

Comment: yes, there's no reference to it any more in the ShowFile action method

Comment: I suspect that's a separate issue then - if the generated URL is the same upto the # character then it's being handled the same on the server - the server never sees the # part of the URL.

Comment: Seemed to be an issue with my app key I was using as a switch for determining the location of the file for Test and Live environments. I published my changes to the live environment and your suggested changes worked perfectly fine. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75845/discussion-between-tomuke-and-richard).